# Is it possible to groupBy few columns and show all columns of a dataset?

Tags: apache-spark

I want to know if something like the following would be correct (JAVA) to select all original columns while grouping by just a few of them :

```
dF.select("col0","col1","col2","col3","col4").where("col1> mynewmeancol2").groupBy("col0", "col1").agg(avg("col1"))
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Spark will just ignore the other column that are not grouped by or aggregated

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Window` or `groupBy` and follow with the join to original dataframe.

```
dF.select("col0","col1","col2","col3","col4").where("col1> mynewmeancol2")
.withColumn("avgCol1", avg("col1").over(Window.partitionBy("col0", "col1")))
```

Comment: don't you want to create a new column with avg value? Its a new column name for the `avg("col1")`

Comment: alright how do you import `Window`  in JAVA

Comment: This should do  `import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window`

Comment: PartitionBy is only seperating inside the same dataset the rows according to the column values, but how to access and get each partition seperately ?

Comment: what do you mean by get each partition separate? why do you need need the individual partition? is this what you want `df.repartition("foe1").foreachPartition();`

Comment: Yes ok, what is "foe1"?

Comment: Here you can add the column name or expression.

Comment: By the way, i don't want to add a new column "avgCol1" actually, mynewmeancol2 is the average column, but i want to groupy while filtering / splitting the dataset by the mynewmeancol2 (the average of col1)

Comment: Can you add the expected output ? may be with some sample data?

Comment: i am asking you this : is it possible to keep `.over(Window.partitionBy("col0", "col1")` on the first part of your code answer (and so remove the part `.withColumn("avgCol1...", `) ?

Comment: In that case you can just replace with withColumn part with  `.withColumn("mynewmeancol2", avg("col1").over(Window.partitionBy("col0", "col1")))`

Comment: You just replacing avgCol1 with mynewmeancol2, what i want is to groupBy (partitionBy) without adding another column

Comment: Also how to pass an array of column names to partitionBy rather than col0 & col1 ?

Comment: But you said you want all the columns, if you use groupBy you will loose the columns that are not included in the groupBy and aggregation, You have to join to the original dataframe again to get all columns.